# Python: Save a hex string to a jpg image file

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, hex, jpeg

I have multiple hex strings like this one (big string so I truncated the middle):

> 0xFFD8FFEE000E41646F626500640000000002FFE11E2445786966000049492A006A0500002C010000010000002C0100000100000041646F62652050686F746F73686F702043533620284D6163................................................................................................................................................................7D8D9DAE1E2E3E4E5E6E7E8E9EAF1F2F3FF7F8F9FAFFC4001F0100030101010101010101010000000000000102030405060708090A0BFFC400B511000201020404030407050404000102770

I want to save each string in a file. But my code is not working well:

```
import binascii

data = binascii.a2b_hex(my_hex_string)
with open('/path/image.jpg', 'wb') as image_file:
    image_file.write(data)
```

I receive this error:

> TypeError: Odd-length string

When I remove the first `0` I get this:

> TypeError: Non-hexadecimal digit found

When I remove the two first chars (since JPG is supposed to start with FF D8), I get this again:

> TypeError: Odd-length string

Any ideas please?

Comment: Maybe you be better off removing the **last** `0` instead.

Comment: *how* do you remove the first 2 characters? Does the string contain new lines?

Comment: Thank you for your replies guys, When I remove the last 0 as Mathias suggests I receive the following error when opening the file: "Error interpreting JPEG image file (Improper call to JPEG library in state 201)". and Yes I stripped the string it does not contain any new lines

Comment: Do you use `strip` on `data` or on `my_hex_string`?

Comment: Hi Samuel, on my_hex_string

Comment: @Oussama updated my answer. please check

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I tested your code. I think there is nothing wrong with your code. Just try to remove the `0x` from the beginning of your Hex Codes. I think that would work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the string doesn't have something extra in it? Whitespace, newlines, etc?

Try `my_hex_string.strip()`

Also, there is possibility, you can have spaces inside the string, so you can do something like that to clean them out:

```
binascii.a2b_hex(toSend.replace(' ', ''))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but no there is no newlines nor whitespaces I did strip it

Answer (score 0):

3.5 yo thread. But is getting many views, so I will add my 2c. OP's code works just fine for me. My guess is that the hex string is corrupted. Most prominantly, not seeing an [FFD9 for "end of image."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG)